# Can not load Project after fetch or pull .xcodeproj file from git server

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Our project managed by git, and team members commit thier .xcodeproj file when they add or delete files in the project.
(we use sourcetree + bitbucket)

The problem is, when team members fetch (or pull) commited .xcodeproj file, they can not load their project anymore in Xcode.

What is problem of this and how to solve the problem ?

Is there any thing to be careful when commit .xcodeproj file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your file permissions are not saved.
Git store permission as 
Change the execute permission to the file & then set this config value so git will track the

```
# Tell git not to ignore file permissions
git config core.fileMode true
```

> #### core.fileMode
>
> ```
> If false, the executable bit differences between the index and the
> working copy are ignored; useful on broken filesystems like FAT.
> ```